# DocuSign OrgAdmin API > Unauthorized when updating users

Tags: docusignapi

I use Authorization code grant flow

When trying to update user from OrgAdmin API I always get “Unauthorized”:

```
{
    "error": "unauthorized",
    "error_description": "Not Authorized",
    "reference_id": "7da40c89-bb98-4eb2-829b-5ef604267175" 
}
```

Checked those endpoints:

- POST https://api-d.docusign.net/management/v2/organizations/{{organizationId}}/users    (https://developers.docusign.com/orgadmin-api/reference/Users/Users/createUser)
- POST https://api-d.docusign.net/management/v2/organizations/{{organizationId}}/accounts/{{accountId}}/users    (https://developers.docusign.com/orgadmin-api/reference/Users/Users/addUsers)

I have already checked:

1. "user_write" permission is on my list of requested scopes
   https://account-d.docusign.com/oauth/auth?response_type=code&scope=user_write user_read&client_id=xxxx-...&state=xxxxxx&redirect_uri=http://localhost:51820
2. The user that calls the APIs is actually OrgAdmin (checked from the Admin UI)

I am out of ideas. What could be wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like ambiguous error response.

The problem was in below part of user creation JSON

```
"auto_activate_memberships" : "true"
```

When I changed it to "false", I was able to create users normally.